# Full text Search in SQL Server not finding my entries

Tags: sql, sql-server, full-text-search, ssms

My requirement is to be able to search `imran` in `Simran`, `Simrankaur` e.t.c

I am using following query:

```
select Name, Len(Name)
from Demo 
where Contains(Name, '"*imran*"')
```

My `Demo` table has `Name` column with following entries `Simran`, `Simrankaur`, `SimranKaurKhurana` but the query returns nil.

Where am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you want `like`:

```
select Name, Len(Name)
from Demo
where Name like '%imran%';
```

Even if you use contains, you can't use a wildcard at the beginning of the string.

Comment: Oh, is that? That answers my question :) Thanks.

Comment: Yet, just wanted to know since it is called Full text search, is there really no way to use something of the kind in CONTAINS ?

Comment: @Simran . . . According to the documentation (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187787.aspx) you can search for a prefix but not an arbitrary substring.

Comment: Thanks and what if I need to search for an arbitrary string?

Answer (score 1):

Try  the following if your database is not case sensitive

```
select Name, Len(Name) from Demo 
where Name like '%imran%'
```

Note that depending on database settings this may be case sensitive,
so this might be more consistent:

```
select Name, Len(Name) from Demo 
where LOWER(Name) like '%imran%'
```

Comment: `Contains` is a native function in SQL server